# How much gas does msg.gas statement use?

Tags: solidity, evm

If I use `msg.gas` statement inside my contract, does executing that line itself need gas? If yes, how much does it need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `msg.gas` is deprecated. You should use `gasleft()` if you are over version `0.4.21`.

The function itself uses the `gas` opcode which is in the base group and thus costs **2 gas**.

Answer (score 1):

`msg.gas` was renamed to `gasleft()`.

Anyway, everything has a cost, for `gasleft()` it is defined [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/496f05cf52f2b7f1baaa064eee49aea8ed604ec8/core/vm/jump_table.go#L568). The associated cost is [`GasQuickStep`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/gas.go#L25) which is set to 2.

It therefore cost you 2 gas to know how much gas is left.